# Server-side pagination and search with Vuetify <v-data-table>

Tags: vue.js, pagination, axios, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm currently making a CRUD app that consists of a data table of movies. I'm using themoviedb as my API and VueJS, vuetify, axios and vuex. I'm trying to implement the server-side pagination and search but I'm getting a lot of errors. Here's what I've got so far: (I know it's probably a mess, but I'm learning)

My App component

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-card style="padding: 70px 60px 70px 70px;
                background-color: black;
                background-size: 1500px 2000px;" 
                >
          <v-card color="blue accent-4" 
                style="padding: 10px;box-shadow: 1px 3px 62px 0px rgba(255,0,255,1);"
                class="elevation-3">
            <v-data-table
              :items="movies"
              :headers="headers"
              :options.sync="options"
            >
              <template v-slot:top>
                <v-toolbar flat
                          style="background-color: #504a4a; color: white"
                >
                  <v-toolbar-title>
                      POPULAR MOVIES
                  </v-toolbar-title>
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="search"
                    append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                    label="search"
                    single-line
                    hide-details
                    style="margin-left: 150px"
                    dark
                  ></v-text-field>
                  <v-divider
                    class="mx-4"
                    inset
                    vertical
                  ></v-divider>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <new-movie></new-movie>
            </v-toolbar>
          </template>
              <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
                <v-btn color="blue accent-4" dark small class="mr-1 mb-2" @click.stop="{
                  detail = { 
                    Title: item.title, 
                    Overview: item.overview, 
                    Votes: item.vote_average, 
                    Date: item.release_date,
                    Path: item.poster_path
                    }
                  }"
                >
                  Read More
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue accent-4" dark small class="mr-1 mb-2" @click.stop="{edit = {id: item.id, title: item.title, overview: item.overview, votes: item.vote_average}}">Edit</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue accent-4" dark small class="mr-1 mb-2" @click.stop="idMovie = item.id">Delete</v-btn>
              </template>      
            </v-data-table>
            <details-movie v-model="detail"
            ></details-movie>
            <edit-movie v-model="edit"></edit-movie>
            <delete-movie v-model="idMovie"></delete-movie>
        </v-card>
      </v-card>  
    </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex';
import deleteMovie from './components/deleteMovie.vue';
import detailsMovie from './components/detailsMovie.vue';
import editMovie from './components/editMovie.vue';
import newMovie from './components/newMovie.vue';
export default {
  components: { detailsMovie, editMovie, newMovie, deleteMovie }, 
  name: 'App',

  data: function() {
    return {
      detail: null,
      edit: null,
      search: '',
      idMovie: null, 
      options: {},
    }
  },
  computed: {
    headers() {
      return [
                {text: "Title", value: "title"},
                {text: "Overview", value: "overview"},
                {text: "Votes", value:"vote_average"},
                {text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false},
      ]
    },

    ...mapState({
            movies:state => state.movies
    }),

  
  },
  watch: {
    options: {
        handler () {
          this.$store.dispatch('getMovies')
        },
        deep: true,
      }
    },
  
  }

</script>
```

My index.js in /store

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
import {public_key} from '../movie'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    movies: [],
    options: {
      page: 0,
    },
  },
  
  mutations: {
 
    SET_MOVIES(state, movies) {
      state.movies = movies
      movies.forEach(item => {
        movies.push(item)
        console.log(item)
      });
    },

    NEW_MOVIE(state, newMovie){
      console.log(newMovie)
      let movies = state.movies.concat(newMovie);
      state.movies = movies
    },

    DELETE_MOVIE(state, idMovie){
      let movies = state.movies.filter( m => m.id != idMovie)
      state.movies = movies;
    },

    EDIT_MOVIE(state, editedMovie){
      state.movies.forEach( m => {  
        if(m.id == editedMovie.id) {
          m = editedMovie;
        }
      })
    },

    SET_PAGINATION(state, options){
      const page = options
    }
      
  },

  actions: {
  
    async getMovies({commit}){
      let response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=${public_key}&language=en-US`)
      .then((response) => {
        commit('SET_MOVIES', response.data.results)
        commit('SET_PAGINATION', response.data.page)
      });
     },
     
      async addMovie({commit}, newMovie){
        console.log(newMovie)
       commit('NEW_MOVIE', newMovie)
     },

     async deleteM({commit}, idMovie){
        console.log(idMovie)
        commit('DELETE_MOVIE', idMovie)
   },
      async editMovie({commit}, editedMovie){
        console.log(editedMovie.id)
        commit('EDIT_MOVIE', editedMovie);
      }

   },
 })
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: page is not defined
    at Store.SET_PAGINATION (index.js?4360:46)
    at wrappedMutationHandler (vuex.esm.js?2f62:844)
    at commitIterator (vuex.esm.js?2f62:466)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (vuex.esm.js?2f62:465)
    at Store._withCommit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:624)
    at Store.commit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:464)
    at boundCommit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:409)
    at eval (index.js?4360:56)
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Where are your errors?

Comment: I just edited the question with the error ;) the app is still working but i dont think the pagination is, and the search is simply not doing anything

Answer (score 0):

You committed

```
commit('SET_PAGINATION', response.data.page)
```

But didn't use `page` in `SET_PAGINATION`, Could change to :

```
SET_PAGINATION(state, page){
  state.options.page = page 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It got rid of the error, but search is not working yet, I don't really know what to implement for it to work